# Данные из формы считываются слишком рано

Tags: php, html

Здраствуйте!
Есть простенькая форма с двумя полями для ввода и кнопкой.

```
 <form action="ex1.php" method="$_GET">
        <input type="text" name="x" value="">
        <input type="text" name="y" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

И скрипт, который должен работать с этой формой:

```
<?php
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    $y = $_GET['y'];
    echo $x, '-', $y, '=', $x - $y, '</br>';
    echo $x, '*', $y, '=', $x * $y, '</br>';
    echo $x, '%', $y, '=', $x % $y, '</br>';
?>
```

Проблема в том, что данные из формы скрипт пытается считать сразу после загрузки страницы, т.е пользователь ещё не успел ввести данные, а скрипт уже отработал.

[image: Ошибка]

Понимаю почему так происходит, но не понимаю, как исправить. Буду благодарен за объяснение.

Comment: наверное, над проверить, была ли отправлена форма?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит проверять переменные на существование методом isset().

```
if(isset($_GET['x']) && isset($_GET['y'])){
     $x = $_GET['x'];
    $y = $_GET['y'];
    echo $x, '-', $y, '=', $x - $y, '</br>';
    echo $x, '*', $y, '=', $x * $y, '</br>';
    echo $x, '%', $y, '=', $x % $y, '</br>';
}
```

И еще, в теге `form` метод передачи запроса указан не верно. Сейчас так  `<form action="ex1.php" method="$_GET">` а надо так  `<form action="ex1.php" method="GET">`. GET вместо $_GET.

Comment: GET вообще указывать не надо. как и адрес той же страницы. То есть можно написать просто `<form>`